# Why is my Quicktime plugin transport bar black?

Tags: browser, toolbar, quicktime

For some reason when streaming quicktime movies with the browser plug-in the transport bar is completely black. I can still use it but I can't actually see any of the buttons. Any clue how to fix this?

I've updated to the latest version of quicktime but it didn't help.

This behavior is the same in both firefox and chrome.

Comment: I have the same issue I just thought the bar was gone and the video had a black bar lol

Comment: Yeah, you can still control the volume by clicking in the lower left of the black bar right?

Comment: +1 I've had the same problem also. It's quite inconvenient to not be able to see a progress bar and know the location of the buttons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd check: http://www.apple.com/quicktime/download/ for updates. They recently released 7.6.6 not to long ago and it fixed my Quicktime plugin transport bar.

Comment: Thanks for the update. The latest (as of this writing) fixed it. Looks like I just needed to wait a bit.

Comment: Yeah, it was a big relief when the new update came out and fixed the transport bar. I guess it was just a bug. Hopefully it won't come back.

Comment: Wow they finally fixed. I've had this bug for years.